# timer implementd on fd

Tags: linux, timer

To implement a timer, I'm currently forking a process that uses SIGALRM to periodically wake it and write a byte into a pipe.  I'm aware of `signalfd` for receiving signals on a file descriptor and I'd like to do the same with a timer, but all of the timer mechanisms I'm aware of use signals.  Does Linux provide a mechanism to provide a timer via a file descriptor?

Comment: select/poll with timeout, epoll with timeout or timerfd...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [timerfd_create](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html) and friends. It is a linux specific syscall.